# SetMaxOpenConns and SetMaxIdleConns

Tags: database, go

Why are there `SetMaxOpenConns` and `SetMaxIdleConns`. In the [doc](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns)

**SetMaxIdleConns**

> SetMaxIdleConns sets the maximum number of connections in the idle
>   connection pool.
>
> If MaxOpenConns is greater than 0 but less than the new MaxIdleConns
>   then the new MaxIdleConns will be reduced to match the MaxOpenConns
>   limit
>
> If n <= 0, no idle connections are retained.

**SetMaxOpenConns**

> SetMaxOpenConns sets the maximum number of open connections to the
>   database.
>
> If MaxIdleConns is greater than 0 and the new MaxOpenConns is less
>   than MaxIdleConns, then MaxIdleConns will be reduced to match the new
>   MaxOpenConns limit
>
> If n <= 0, then there is no limit on the number of open connections.
>   The default is 0 (unlimited).

Why have both functions but not a single function to adjust both idle and open connections like `MaxConns` which is `MaxIdleConns + MaxOpenConns`. Why would a developer have to arrange how many open and idle conns there can be instead of defining the total pool?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The db pool may contain 0 or more idle connections to the database. These were connections that were made, used, and rather than closed, were kept around for future use. The number of these we can keep around is `MaxIdleConns`.

When you request one of these idle connections, it becomes an Open connection, available for you to use. The number of these you can use is `MaxOpenConns`.

Now, there is no point in ever having any more idle connections than the maximum allowed open connections, because if you *could* instantanously grab all the allowed open connections, the remain idle connections would always remain idle. It's like having a bridge with four lanes, but only ever allowing three vehicles to drive across it at once.

Therefore, we would like to ensure that

```
MaxIdleConns <= MaxOpenConns
```

The functions are written to preserve this invariant by reducing `MaxIdleConns` whenever it exceeds `MaxOpenConns`. Note that the documentation says, only `MaxIdleConns` is ever reduced to match `MaxOpenConns`, the latter is never true.

To answer the question of why a developer might want to adjust these separately: consider the case of an application that is usually quiet, but occasionally needs to open a large number of connections. You may wish to specify a large `MaxOpenConns`, but a very small `MaxIdleConns`, to ensure that your application can open as many connections in requires whenever it needs to, but releases these resources quickly, freeing up memory both for itself *and* the database. Keeping an idle connection alive is not free, and it's usually done because you want to turn it into usable connection soon.

So the reason there are two numbers here is that these are two parameters that you might have a good reason to vary individually. Of course, the semantics of the API mean that if you don't care about setting both these values, you can just set the one that you care about, which is probably `MaxOpenConns`

Comment: The part where i didn't get it why isn't there something like `MaxConns` which is `MaxIdleConns + MaxOpenConns`. Why would a developer have to arrange how many open and idle there can be? Edited the question for more understability.

Comment: Because you could desire to have `MaxIdleConns` be low, but your `MaxOpenConns` to be high. This means that your application can open as many connections as it needs, while it needs them, but consumes minimal resources when it doesn't: suitable for a bursty load.

Comment: What is considered a idle connection in this case?

Comment: how would I know what exactly number we have to put in MaxOpenConns and  MaxIdleConns?