# what is the best solutions to mysql connection timeout?

Tags: mysql, go

I am writing a small web app in Go, which uses mysql to store data.

I got intermittent mysql error if the web sever didn't get any request after some amount of time(> 8 hours):

```
[mysql] 2017/02/08 16:31:56 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2017/02/08 16:31:56 packets.go:130: write tcp 127.0.0.1:49188->127.0.0.1:3306: write: broken pipe
```

I found some related discussion on github([issue 529](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/529), [issue 257](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/257) and [issue 446](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/446)). From what I understand, mysql db would close the connection if timeout is reached.

I tried to set `SetMaxOpenConns` to 9 and `SetMaxIdleConns` to 0 as some people recommended. However, this threw exception immediately. (But if I set `SetMaxIdleConns` larger than 0, there was no immediate exception thrown)

I also tried to set `SetConnMaxLifetime` to 5 mins. This threw exception too after 5 mins.

Now I am trying the code below:

```
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(0)
db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
db.SetMaxIdleConns(5)
```

It has been running for 20 mins. It's still too early to tell.
(UPDATE: this doesn't work either)

Here is configuration:

- driver: go-sql-driver V1.3.
- go version: go1.7.1 darwin/amd64
- mysql: [latest from docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
- rkt version: 1.18
- CoreOS: 1284.0.0

Answer (score 3):

1. you can check your mysql time_wait variable:

   ```
   mysql> show global variables like 'wait_timeout':
   +---------------+-------+
   | Variable_name | Value |
   +---------------+-------+
   | wait_timeout  | 300   |
   +---------------+-------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
2. then use `db.SetConnMaxLifetime(120*time.Second)`, which mean when db connection is idle over than 120s, sql.db will reopen or get a new connection from db pool by `db.Open`. If you not set connection max life time, you maybe use a closed connection and got the error.
3. watching the mysql process list，`mysql> show processlist;`，if connection sleep over than 300s，it's recycled by mysql:

   ```
   mysql> show processlist;
   +-------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------+
   | Id    | User            | Host             | db          | Command | Time    | State                  | Info             |
   +-------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------+
   |     4 | event_scheduler | localhost        | NULL        | Daemon  | 1363480 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL             |
   | 26539 | root            | 172.17.0.1:48732 | NULL        | Query   |       0 | starting               | show processlist |
   | 26575 | auditcenter     | 172.17.0.1:51714 | obs_gb_test | Sleep   |      51 |                        | NULL             |
   +-------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------------------+
   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
4. `SetMaxOpenConns` and `SetMaxIdleConns` is used for setting connection resource, see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952791/setmaxopenconns-and-setmaxidleconns)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can start a heartbeat Goroutine to avoid timeout.

Comment: would  `for { db.ping()}` be good enough as a heartbeat goroutine?

Comment: or maybe `{for {db.Exec("DO 42")}}` is better given the suggestions at https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/498

Comment: Might want to put that on a time.Ticker, there's no need to have it ping as fast as it can.

Comment: yep, it's a good idea to use ticker. Thanks for your suggestion.