# sqlx write: broken pipe

Tags: mysql, sql, go, mariadb

I am trying to update a huge text into a MariaDB table but keep getting `broken pipe` errors. The column has a `longtext` data type and from my logs it looks like the data has a size of `~1374069 bytes`.

I've tried updating the `MaxConnLife` to several different values like half of my `wait_timeout` from MariaDB which is set to `28800` ->  `db.SetConnMaxLifetime(14400)`

This is what my DB conn looks like

```
    loggerAdapter := zerologadapter.New(zerolog.New(os.Stdout))
    db := sqldblogger.OpenDriver(dsn, &mysql.MySQLDriver{}, loggerAdapter /*, using_default_options*/) // db is STILL *sql.DB

    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(14400)


    sqlxdb := sqlx.NewDb(db, "MySQL")
```

error log

```
{"level":"info","conn_id":"66g4YSswso2QqsQE","duration":0.289406,"query":"UPDATE campaigns SET vendor_products=? WHERE id=?","stmt_id":"Mygo_MuAaIuGYwe2","time":1605747034,"message":"PrepareContext"} 
[mysql] 2020/11/19 00:50:34 packets.go:145: write tcp IP->IP: write: broken pipe 
{"level":"ERROR","args":["[{\"Id\":1,\"UserId\":1,\"PlanId\":1,\"GroupI (1374069 bytes truncated)",130],"conn_id":"66g4YSswso2QqsQE","duration":2.138179,"ERROR":"invalid connection","query":"UPDATE campaigns SET vendor_products=? WHERE id=?","stmt_id":"Mygo_MuAaIuGYwe2","time":1605747034,"message":"StmtExecContext"} 
{"level":"ERROR","conn_id":"66g4YSswso2QqsQE","duration":0.00295,"ERROR":"driver: bad connection","query":"UPDATE campaigns SET vendor_products=? WHERE id=?","stmt_id":"Mygo_MuAaIuGYwe2","time":1605747034,"message":"StmtClose"}
```

Versions I am using

```
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.1
go 1.13
github.com/jmoiron/sqlx v0.0.0-20181024163419-82935fac6c1a
```

Any idea how I can solve this? Or should I just think of another solution? Like possibly storing this text to S3 instead of SQL?

I've done some research but none of these helped. Some of the stuff I found.

- https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/446
- [what is the best solutions to mysql connection timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127441/what-is-the-best-solutions-to-mysql-connection-timeout)
- https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/529
- https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/116

Comment: Look for memory limits on the driver or the server. This doesn't look like a timeout issue.

Comment: It looks like increasing max_allowed_packet will solve my issue. https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/ I just tried in my local and it worked, will try on our remote servers tomorrow.

Comment: @ET2019 that's great. You should write this in as your own answer ro your own question `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the `max_allowed_packet` answers my question.

Reference: https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/max_allowed_packet/